# Android - observing DB changes within ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I am using a lot of LiveData in my projects and it's great in those cases where I need to pass something to views since it's intention is to be observed by lifecycle owners (i.e. views).

But I wonder what should I use in those cases when I need to apply some logic in my view models every time when some data from DB changes?

I am familiar with Transformations (map and switch) but (if I am right) they are just a way to transform liveData objects, not a place where I can execute some viewmodel's logic.

If I understand correctly, observing LiveData in viewModels is bad practice. 
What is an alternative? Some of the RxJava observable types? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

> "they are just a way to transform liveData objects, not a place where I can execute some viewmodel's logic."

Yes you're right. It's because:

> Functions in both map() and switchMap() run on the Main Thread,
>   so no long running operations should be done there!

But I don't think observing LiveData in ViewModel is bad practice, because in Android we have **MediatorLiveData** for this purpose. If you take a look at source code of **map** and **switchMap** function, you'll see they use **MediatorLiveData** in there.

So the only problem here is that if *some logic* you want to execute is a long running task, you must run it in background thread when observe changes from the source LiveData. You can use Rx or something to run it in background thread like below:

```
private val _downloadState = MutableLiveData<DownloadDataState>()
val downloadState: LiveData<DownloadDataState> = _downloadState

// version observe changes in downloadState
val version = MediatorLiveData<String>().apply {
    addSource(downloadState) {

        // Whenever value of downloadState changes, this block will run your logic

        Single.just(dataRepository.fetchDataVersion())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { result ->
                    // Then set value to the observer 
                    value = result
                },
                { e: Throwable ->
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            )
    }
}
```